# background color and sub menu constantly toggling hover state in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This has been the bane of my week at the moment. Basically i have a pure CSS drop down menu that combines both standard lists and content boxes as sub menus. I am having trouble specifically in IE where each LI has an  tag that is display block, so should fill the parent LI. so i am able to hover and click anywhere in the LI and the links hover, active states are on.

what's happening is in IE if i hover over the text the hover state styles are applied with no issue, however if i move the mouse off the text but still within the LI the hover is constantly being applied and then removed (see [dev.altech-uk.com](http://dev.altech-uk.com)).

It is slightly annoying because the sub-menus are then flickering on and off all the time and also you may miss the sub menu. None of this happens in FF, chrome, opera, safari.

Heres the CSS code regarding to this:

```
div.navBG ul.navMenu {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; display: block; padding: 0; height: 35px; text-align: center;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li {display: inline-block; list-style: none; position: relative; margin: 0 -4px; padding: 0;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li:hover:after {bottom: 0; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 999;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li:hover:after {border-color: rgba(146, 200, 236, 0); border-bottom-color: #92C8EC; border-width: 10px; left: 50%; margin-left: -10px;}

div.navBG ul.navMenu > li > a {display: block; line-height: 35px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; font-size: 11px; color: #FFF; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li > a:hover {background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #162d54 13%, #002d5e 28%, #0f233d 61%); background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(13%,#162d54), color-stop(28%,#002d5e), color-stop(61%,#0f233d)); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #162d54 13%,#002d5e 28%,#0f233d 61%); background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #162d54 13%,#002d5e 28%,#0f233d 61%); background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #162d54 13%,#002d5e 28%,#0f233d 61%); background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #162d54 13%,#002d5e 28%,#0f233d 61%); -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#162d54', endColorstr='#0f233d',GradientType=0 )";}
/*div.navBG ul.navMenu > li:hover {background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #162d54 13%, #002d5e 28%, #0f233d 61%); background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(13%,#162d54), color-stop(28%,#002d5e), color-stop(61%,#0f233d)); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #162d54 13%,#002d5e 28%,#0f233d 61%); background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #162d54 13%,#002d5e 28%,#0f233d 61%); background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #162d54 13%,#002d5e 28%,#0f233d 61%); background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #162d54 13%,#002d5e 28%,#0f233d 61%); -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#162d54', endColorstr='#0f233d',GradientType=0 )";}*/
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.subMenuContainer {max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 35px; visibility: hidden; z-index: 999; width: 270px; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li .rightout {right: -8px;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.subMenuContainer > ul {background: #92C8EC; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; white-space: no-wrap; width: 270px; position: relative;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.subMenuContainer:after {z-index: 9999; bottom: 0; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; border-bottom-color: #92C8EC; border-width: 15px; left: 50%; margin-left: -15px; border-color: rgba(146, 200, 236, 0);}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.subMenuContainer > ul li {display: block; margin: 0; position: relative; vertical-align: text-top; font-size: 11px;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.subMenuContainer > ul li h4 {font-weight: 700; background: url(/img/sitewide/icon.png) no-repeat 3px center; color: #003975; font-size: 14px; padding: 7px 0 5px 42px; margin: 0; text-align: left;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.subMenuContainer > ul li a {color: #FFF; display: block; padding-left: 20px; line-height: 35px; text-decoration: none; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; font-size: 1em !important; text-align: left;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.subMenuContainer > ul li a:hover {background: #3C7FAB !important;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li:hover div.subMenuContainer {visibility: visible;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li:hover .solution {max-height: 300px;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li:hover .machines {max-height: 600px;}

/*div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.navMenuItemPane a.cp, 
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.navMenuItemPane a.cp:active, 
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.navMenuItemPane a.cp:visited {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;}*/
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li:hover div.navMenuItemPaneContainer {max-height: 300px; z-index: 99; height: auto; visibility: visible;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.navMenuItemPaneContainer {background: #92C8EC; box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); width: 540px; visibility: hidden; left: 0; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 35px; z-index: 99; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;} 
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.navMenuItemPaneContainer > ul {width: 540px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.navMenuItemPaneContainer > ul li {display: inline; float: left; font-size: 11px; vertical-align: text-top; position: relative;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.navMenuItemPaneContainer > ul li a {color: #FFF; display: block; padding-left: 20px; line-height: 35px; text-decoration: none; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; font-size: 1em !important; text-align: left;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.navMenuItemPaneContainer > ul li a:hover {background: #3C7FAB !important;}
div.navBG ul.navMenu > li div.navMenuItemPaneContainer h4 {font-weight: 700; background: url(/img/sitewide/icon.png) no-repeat 3px center; color: #003975; font-size: 14px; padding: 7px 0 5px 42px; margin: 0; text-align: left;}
#double li {width: 50%;}
```

Any assistance here will be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the filter: progid...etc. from div.navBG ul.navMenu >li > a:hover